# How to change file extension using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using swift code but is not changed file extension.

This my swift code

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputURL.path).deletingPathExtension?.appendingPathExtension("mp3")
```

Comment: Why do you create an `URL` from an URL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are just creating a `URL` and then changing that `URL`. You are not actually operating on any file.

To rename a file, call [`FileManager.default.moveItem(at:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1414750-moveitem). Pass the file URL as the first argument, and the file URL with the new name as the second argument.

```
let newURL = outputURL.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("mp3")
try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: outputURL, to: newURL)
```

Comment: It would be `URL(fileURLWithPath: outputURL.path)` in Swift 4 (without `!`) – but that is identical to `outputURL`

Comment: @MartinR I wasn't sure whether `outputURL` would be of type `URL`, but if you think it is, then sure :)